# Android Studio-Can't Generate APK

Tags: android, apk, generate

When i want to generate the apk this error appears to me :https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdAyR.jpg .
So far I have not received this error, for some time it started to appear and I do not know how to fix it, if anyone can help me, I am waiting for an answer, thanks in advance!

Comment: did you change anything in the values.xml code?...

Comment: Have you tried with Invalidate Cache/ Restart ?

Comment: I haven't changed anything in value.xml

Comment: Yes, I tried with Invalidate Cache / Restart